# Capturar retorno de tela de equipamento OLT CIANET com PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estou tentando capturar dados de uma OLT CIANET via Telnet ou SSH e não venho tendo sucesso, quero saber em qual slot/pon a ONU esta conectada, o comando para exibir as ONUs que utilizo é:

```
show port epon ".$slot."/1-4 onu mac ".$mac." epon-mac-address-table
```

Tentei utilizando uma classe SSH e outra Telnet, não obtive sucesso em nenhuma delas, se alguém tiver uma classe telnet ou ssh, ou exemplo de como enviar e capturar os da OLT, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou usar a função [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php)? o segundo argumento é saida de texto do prompt.

Comment: consegui resolver utilizando ssh2, porem confesso que nao ficou legal, bem dificil capturar os dados de retorno do equipamento...

Comment: Poderia demonstrar como fez? outras pessoas podem ter o mesmo problema.

Comment: sim, perai que vou colocar o script:

Comment: Voce ja pensou em usar o shell exec()?
Acho que seria mais facil.

Comment: Infelizmente um simples shell exec não atenderia a necessidade, pois se trata de uma máquina externa, ou seja, ela deve ser acessada e enviado os comandos para ela remotamente.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 // error_reporting(0);
 $slot = $_GET['slot'];
 $mac  = str_replace(":","",$_GET['mo']);

 $ip   = 'ip_do_equipamento_na_sua_rede';
 $user = 'seu_usuario';
 $pass = 'sua_senha_de_acesso';
 $porta = 'porta_do_socket';
 $cmd = "show port epon ".$slot."/1-4 onu mac '.$mac.' epon-mac-address-table";

 include('../Net/SSH2.php');

 $sftp = new Net_SSH2($ip,$porta);
 $sftp->login($usuario, $pass); 

 $sftp->write("enable\n");
 $sftp->write($cmd."\n");
 $saida = $sftp->read('port '.$slot.'/1');
 $sftp->write("exit\n");
 $saida = $sftp->read('exit');
 $sftp->disconnect();
 $bomba = explode(''.$slot.'/',$saida); // 
 $lin = count($bomba);

 $html = '<script type="text/javascript">'.PHP_EOL;
 for($i=0; $i<$lin; $i++) {
  $pedaco = $bomba[$i];
  $c4 = explode("\n", $pedaco);
  $contador = count($c4);
  $c4 = 1 + $i;
  if($contador > 3) {
   $html .= 'document.getElementById("fish'.$slot.''.$c4.'").innerHTML =
      "<font color=green>&#10004;</font>";';
  } else {
   $html .= 'document.getElementById("fish'.$slot.''.$c4.'").innerHTML =
      "<font color=red>&#10008;</font>";';
  }
 }
 $html .= '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
 echo $html;
 // echo '<pre>'.$html."</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Se puder explicar pq utilizou essa abordagem seria bacana :)

Comment: Fiz este script perdeu, com a finalidade de o usuário não precisar ficar procurando no Mapa de Áreas de Atendimento Fibra, assim economiza-se papel e tempo, além da redução de erros uma vez que verifico na OLT o serial e o mac da onu.